# Is it possible to apply a vanilla Neural Network to Time Series Forecasting?

Tags: neural-network, time-series, forecasting, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently learning about Neural Networks, but I have yet to explore the most successful architectures for forecasting like RNN's and CNN's. I was curious if there was a way to apply a standard network to the task of predicting future values in a Time Series.

If so, is there a way to link these data points before passing them into the network?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a plain feed-forward neural network for time series forecasting by inputting a sliding window of the past `w` values for training and prediction, for some fixed size `w`. This solves the problem of FNN's requiring a fixed-size input.

This is often not as good as using a RNN for various reasons, including that you lose everything that is outside of your fixed window, whereas an RNN automatically decides how many previous examples are relevant.

Comment: So this window would then take in some 'w' points of the time series and then the output layer would represent the next 'w + n' points? I think I'm still a little confused on how training and the cost function would work. Would I just be comparing the next 'n' points on each epoch? Wouldn't the training and test data start to overlap because of the sliding window? If you could expand I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is rather basic "vanilla"  neural network that forecasts time series
using the Joone neural network.

See this example for forecasts. The red line on this plot shows the prediction.

[image]

I've grabbed this example from Datamelt cde example repository https://jwork.org/dmelt/code/